# How to get nicknames from a Google group via API?

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I get an nickname for a group via Google Apps Script?

This doesn't seem to work:

```
  var groups = GroupsManager.getAllGroups();
  for (var i in groups) {
    var group = groups[i];
    var nicknames = NicknameManager.getAllNicknames(group.getName());
```

Comment: I'm afraid this one is electable for the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) as I can't see any method concerning nickNames on group objects... but you're right, it would be nice to have that at hand ;-)

Comment: +1 as I had completely forgotten that groups could have nicknames - i will be making use of this immediately.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :** *I realize that I misunderstood your question, I'll leave it there just in case in might be of some interrest for someone but it doesn't answer your real question about nickNames of the group itself... sorry*

The argument needed in `getAllNickNames(String username)` is not the group name but a user name in that group. (use control+space to see autocomplete)

Try this code to see the users and their nicknames (I limited execution to 10 because I have a LOT of groups in my domain and it took sooooo long ;-)

```
function myFunction() {
  var groups = GroupsManager.getAllGroups();
  for (var i in groups) {
    if(i>10){break}
    var groupName = groups[i].getName()
    var groupUsers = groups[i].getAllMembers()
    for(var u in groupUsers){
      Logger.log('groupName : '+groupName+' = '+groupUsers[u])
    }
  }
    var nicknames = NicknameManager.getAllNicknames()
    for(n in nicknames){
      Logger.log('user '+nicknames[n].getUsername()+' has nickName = '+nicknames[n].getNickname())
    }
}
```